# login access able by level 1 and 2 users php

Tags: php, login-script

> please i want to make my login page to grant users access from level 1 and 2 here is the code .

i don't know the next step from here

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM affiliateuser WHERE (username = '" .  mysqli_real_escape_string($con,$_POST['username']) . "') AND (password = '" .    mysqli_real_escape_string($con,$_POST['password']) . "') AND (active = '" . mysqli_real_escape_string($con,"1") . "')";
if ($result = $mysqli->query($query)) {
if ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
    if($row['level'] == 1 || $row['level'] == 2) {
        // Set username session variable
    session_start();
    $_SESSION['username'] = $username;

    $errormsg= "
<div class='alert alert-warning' style='opacity: 0.5; background-color: rgb(51, 204, 102);'>   <button type='button' class='close' data-dismiss='alert' aria-label='Close'>     <span aria-hidden='true'>&times;</span>   </button>   <strong>SUCCESS...</strong> Redirecting you to dashboard. </div>";

    echo "<meta http-equiv='refresh' content='=2;dashboard' />";
    }
     else {
        //UNAUTHORIZED
```

please how can i make this work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem is in your actual code, you're only selecting users with level = 1.

The easiest solution would be to update your query to select the users where

```
level IN (1,2)
```

Another solution would be removing your WHERE `level = ...` clause and check that later in your PHP code. This way you could handle WRONG PASSWORD and UNAUTHORIZED errors differently

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM affiliateuser WHERE (username = '" .  mysqli_real_escape_string($con,$_POST['username']) . "') AND (password = '" .    mysqli_real_escape_string($con,$_POST['password']) . "') AND (active = '" . mysqli_real_escape_string($con,"1") . "')";
if ($result = $mysqli->query($query)) {
    if ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        if($row['level'] == 1 || $row['level'] == 2) {
            //ALL GOOD
        } else {
            //UNAUTHORIZED
        }
    } else {
        //WRONG USERNAME/PASSWORD
    }
    $result->close();
}
```

Note: there's no need to `mysql_real_escape_string` a hardcoded string when you're sure of its content: in your example 'level' will always be '1'

Comment: didn't work, when i hit submit i takes me to a blank page  eg. https://website.com/signin.php

Comment: Well if you haven't filled what's going into the conditions (the ALL GOOD part), of course it's not gonna work. If you're not experience with coding in general, stick to first solution: "SELECT * FROM affiliateuser WHERE (username = '" .  mysqli_real_escape_string($con,$_POST['username']) . "') AND (password = '" .    mysqli_real_escape_string($con,$_POST['password']) . "') AND (active = '" . mysqli_real_escape_string($con,"1") . "') AND (level IN(1,2))"

Comment: Have you tried running the query directly into MySQL (phpMyAdmin for example) to see if it returns level 2 users ? this will let you know if the problem is at the database level or at the application level

Comment: it does return level 2 users